In "Dead Tired," who is the character next to Queen Elizabeth's lookalike supposed to impersonate?
Towards the end of the movie Grosse Fatigue (1994) (English: Dead Tired), Michel Blanc, playing himself, has got his identity stolen by a look-alike.
He tries to get a job as a look-alike of himself but is rejected as not similar enough. Just before this rebuttal, one sees him sitting in a row with a bunch of people. The second one, a woman, is clearly trying to look like Queen Elizabeth, then there is a rather good look-alike of Michel Sardou, then three Hitler "look-alikes,"  each more ridiculous than the previous one. But I did not recognise who the first person in that row, a man with a white hat and white-framed glasses, could be impersonating. Any idea?
I tried to get a YouTube video of this scene but failed. And the "full cast and crew" on IMDb does not list any of the look-alikes.



Maybe you can stream it (free of charge) and get a screenshot? watch the movie (just need a free registered account)

@OldPadawan Thanks for the idea !

Elton John, QE2, Sardou, Marlene Dietrich, ??? (who is that?), Hitler, Hitler, Fat Hitler. Who is the woman fifth in line?

@OldPadawan - I've added a linkie to the comment

Mireille Matthieu (singer)

@Valorum I'll put the image in a few minutes, but I can already tell you she is supposed to be Mireille Mathieu, a french singer. Very recognizable to a Frenchman my age. In fact, so recognisable that I suspect she is her, and also Sardou is Sardou. Though they are not in the "cast and crew" of IMDb.

I must be old, because that picture said 'Elton John!' to me instantly.

That's definitely Sir Elton John1.
The women with dark hair is a French singer, Mireille Mathieu.

1. In the movie "Grosse Fatigue", the actor seems to be a French kinesiologist playing Sir Elton John. Here's an interview (in French) of him for a late show, wearing the same kind of outfit (at least, the hat). In the movie, it's probably not the real Elton John playing himself :) even though he sometimes has a cameo or plays a small role in films and there's no credit for Sir Elton John anywhere for this role in the movie.

A bit cruel, isn't it ?

Why cruel @Alfred ?  It is not unusual for Elton John to wear clothes like this in public.  This is part of his persona.

That's exactly how he was most of his life. A quick search for pictures of him shows hundreds of costumes, hats and glasses like the ones he wears in the movie. He had one of the greatest collection of clothes (mainly for stage) anyone ever had. Sold some of them years ago though IIRC...

I am not sure I fully understand your answer that I accepted to my question: unknown actors are playing the part of jobless characters trying to get a job of impersonators of celebrities, and I would like to know who is the celebrity aimed at by the first in the row.  And your answer helped me realise that the answer was Sir Elton John, just like it would have been QE2 for the second one. But do you mean more than that, namely that the actor is in fact Sir Elton John himself ? This is what I suspect concerning Mireille Mathieu and Michel Sardou, but I do not claim it.

I mean, you used the phrase "hats and glasses like the ones he wears in the movie. " (emphasis is mine) Do you really mean he is the actor in that movie ?

@Alfred: edited the answer to hopefully make it more clear. FWIW, I also believe MM is just an impersonator and not the real one.

@OldPadawan I seem to recall he's made it a yearly sort of thing to sell them.

@UnrelatedString: I found this (unknown to me) summer sale to help AIDS and research foundations (like $ 20+ millions), but I was thinking about an earlier one, years ago... no big deal though :)

@OldPadawan Your answer is much clearer now. As far as MM is concerned, you might well be right, I am just suggesting she might be the real one, but I am not convinced. But if she is not the real one, then she is a really good lookalike. Much better than the one of QE2, or of Marlene Dietrich...  ;)
